# vSphere loose connection

Tags: java, jenkins, vsphere

I have a problem with vSphere on Jenkins
I have a simply test on multi configuration project
after this test i need reboot VM.

I use commands Power Off and then Power On / Resume Vm
I have 14 VM in test environments. 2 or more have always same isue.

[vSphere]

[vSphere] Performing vSphere build step: "Power-Off VM"

[vSphere] Attempting to use server configuration: "bts-esxi41-p.corp"

[vSphere] Shutting Down VM...

[vSphere] Successfully shutdown "ESS_Windows_8_x86"

[vSphere]

[vSphere] Performing vSphere build step: "Power-On/Resume VM"

[vSphere] Attempting to use server configuration: "bts-esxi41-p.corp"

[vSphere] Waiting for IP (VM may be restarted during this time)

[vSphere] null

Build step 'vSphere Build Step' marked build as failure

But VM is ready and have internet connection

Rado

Comment: Do the VMs have VMware Tools installed?

Comment: Which jenkins plugin you are using?

Comment: problem solved... problem was with DHCP.